# Morris.js: Dynamically Updating ymax

Tags: morris.js

I was working on some Morris.js code today and discovered that no matter what I did, after a chart was drawn I could not modify the ymax value (unless the data set changed, in which case the ymax value was automatically calculated again)

I used chart.options["ymax"] as well as chart.options.ymax and with calls to chart.redraw but they never had any effect. If in place of ymax I used "stacked" and set to true/false this works - just not with ymax it seems

Anyone else had a similar problem or have a solution?